# Laravel 4: multiple where with or in eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, query-builder

how to write this condition using laravel eloquent

SQL

```
select count(id) from fight where status = 'finished' and (user1 = 1 or user2 = 1)
```

Laravel (not finished):

```
Fight::where('user1','=',$uid)->orWhere('user2', '=', $uid)->count('id');
```

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the work:

```
Fight::whereStatus('finished')->where(function($q) use ($uid) {
    $q->where('user1',$uid)->orWhere('user2', $uid);
})->count('id');
```

**EDIT**

Answering comment:

```
Fight::whereIn('status', ['finished', 'cancelled'])->where(function($q) use ($uid) {
    $q->where('user1',$uid)->orWhere('user2', $uid);
})->count('id');
```

Comment: thx, how to add (status = 'finished' or status = 'cancelled')